# how to display a message if a product is direct delivery (attribute = yes)

Tags: attributes, shipping, if

I have an attribute called direct delivery. Is there a way to display a message on the shipping method page tell the customer they have a direct delivery item in their cart. The attribute "direct delivery" is a yes/ no attribute.

thank you

Comment: Do you mean the shipping method checkout step?

Comment: Yea the page they choose what delivery rate they want during the checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on method.phtml file.you need get list of product and check it attribute value yes

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item)
        {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                   if($product->getData('attributecode')==1){
             //direct delivery possaible

                }
                }
```